# Why do wider cables have lower resistance if parallel resistors in general increase resistance?

Tags: resistance

So given two resistors both with resistance R, the resistance they would have in parallel would be R*R/(R+R) right? For large R, R^2 increases like a square and 2R increases linearly, so there must exist a real number r such that r^2/2r > r  So why do thicker cables have lower resistance? wouldn't that be like 2 cables of half the width connected in parallel? And then by making the cables long enough we could make their resistances as large as we like so the resistance should be greater than a single cable. What am I missing?

Comment: Fix one. Length or the thickness

Comment: \$R^2/2R\$ is always equal to \$R/2\$ so there's no positive R for which \$R^2/2R > R\$.

Comment: `parallel resistors in general increase resistance?` This is absolutely false. Resistors in SERIES increase resistance. Resistors in PARALLEL decrease resistance

Answer (score 2):

Well, to my knowledge the parallel resistance for two identical resitance will be R/2 since R*R / 2R => R/2

Answer (score 1):

The total resistance of parallel resisters is equal to the reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals.  Not sure where these other formulas are coming from.

Comment: Where you only have two resistors in parallel, your formula reduces to the "product over sum", which is easier to compute in your head.

Comment: \$ \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}} = \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$

Answer (score 0):

While other answers clearly explain why there's no positive R for which the condition R2/2R > R would be true, I would like to make a point about deciding upon thickness and length as you referred both of them in the question.

When you decide upon what thickness of cable to be selected, you also should assert more than just thinking about Resistance as a parameter. Yes, it is a vital parameter to consider, but there are other parameters too. Depending upon the

```
Power loss (Watts) = Current (Amps) Squared x total resistance of the wiring (Ohms)
```

while, the thin wire conducts a certain electricity, but there is more electrical resistance. The thicker wire is like a four lane highway.
The [Resistivity wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistivity) says,

> The larger the cross-sectional area of the conductor, the more electrons per unit length are available to carry the current. As a result, the resistance is lower in larger cross-section conductors.

Speaking of Length as you referred it,

> The number of scattering events encountered by an electron passing through a material is proportional to the length of the conductor. The longer the conductor, therefore, the higher the resistance.

---

Though slightly irrelevant and out of scope, I would still mention it:
Now, someone would say, "I'll always have thicker cables then." I would say, "Have you heard about the [Skin Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are misinterpreting the behavior of $R^2$ /2R.

In the case where R = 1, $R^2$ = 1 and 2R = 2, so the fraction is 1/2.

In the case where R = 2, $R^2$ = 4 and 2R = 4, so the fraction is 1.

In the case where R = 4, $R^2$ = 16 and 2R = 8, so the fraction is 2.

However, in all cases you need to compare the fraction value to the current value of R, rather than just looking at its numeric value.

When R = 1, 1/2 is less than 1, and is obviously one half of one.

When R =  2, 1 is one half of R.

When R = 4, 2 is one half of 4, and so it goes.

So parallel combinations of resistors always have a lower value than any of the individual resistors.